# View - I need both Parent ID and Child ID at the same time

Tags: views

I’m in need of some help with defining a view.

The gist of it is that I need to know the parent term ID as well as the child term id so that I can separate how the custom template displays the results.

let’s say I have the following as one of many entries in my vocabulary named Category.

Debt Management
---Estate Planning

---Event

---Family Life

If a person selects Debt Management the display is one of two ways.

1) If there are items associated with the term Debt Management, then the template displays data links to each item. After that, the children are displayed, but in a different format, yet similar to the above.

2) If there are no items related to Debt Management, then only its children within their format is displayed.

To do the logic I am building in the template, I need to have the value of the parent TID and the child TID for each record returned to the view.

The path in the view is /taxonomy/term/%, which, after preprocessing for this example comes to /category/debt-management

So far I have the view spitting everything I need properly, except being able to get both parent and child TID. Right now I only get the current displayed item’s TID, which does not allow me to know if it is the parent or not.

I also need to do this with views alone. Not a custom module.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To do rudimentary conditionals with views, you can use two views, and in the first view you select "render a view" on "no results."

Let me break it down a little further for you:

1. Make your "selection" a contextual filter, for default you can select "display a summary" (or something similar to that
2. If the contextual filter has results, display the results.
3. If the contextual filter doesn't have results, choose a "no results" action called "render a view"
4. Create a secondary view that selects all children based on the same contextual filter.